# Magento 2 Minicart - Display line item subtotal rather than unit price

Tags: magento2, price, knockoutjs, mini-cart

**In the Magento 2 mini cart I would like to display the line item subtotal rather than unit price.**

So in the example below the price in the minicart should be $90 because I've added two watches to the cart.

[image]

I see this Magento displays this price from a KnockoutJS template

```
app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/item/default.html
```

with this piece of code:

```
<!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
    <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

The `item` object contains item data like below:

```
canApplyMsrp:false
is_visible_in_site_visibility:true
item_id:"155"
product_has_url:true
product_id:"2"
product_image:Object
product_name:"Test Product"
product_price:"↵↵    <span class="price-excluding-tax" data-label="Excl. Tax">↵            <span class="minicart-price">↵            <span class="price">$45.00</span>        </span>↵↵        </span>↵"
product_price_value:30
product_sku:"01002"
product_type:"simple"
product_url:"http://dev.example.com/test-product.html"
qty:2
```

**In my theme, how can I override the current price value used, `product_price`, to display the line item sub-total price instead?** Properly formatted with the correct currency symbol.

So far I've tried the below:

```
<!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price * item.qty, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->  // returns a NaN

<!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price_value * item.qty, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->  // returns the correct price but without the currency symbol
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set line item subtotal using below way, You dont need to use of knockout js anyway you can just setup your goal using below way,

You can get item qty using `$qty = $item->getQty();`
Now just you have to set `$block->getUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()*$qty` to get lineItem subtotal for each item.

```
You just need to override template file into your theme or module.
I have just setup using override template into theme,
```

**Final Solution,**

**app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Weee/templates/checkout/cart/item/price/sidebar.phtml**

```
<?php
/** @var $block \Magento\Weee\Block\Item\Price\Renderer */
$item = $block->getItem();

$originalZone = $block->getZone();
$block->setZone(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_CART);
/* custom logic*/
$qty = $item->getQty();
?>
<?php if ($block->displayPriceInclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
    <span class="price-including-tax" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Incl. Tax')); ?>">
    <?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
        <span class="minicart-tax-total">
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="minicart-price">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- custom logic -->
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()*$qty); ?>
        </span>

    <?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item)): ?>
            <span class="minicart-tax-info">
            <?php foreach ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item) as $tax): ?>
                <span class="weee" data-label="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $tax['title']; ?>">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($tax['amount_incl_tax'], true, true); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </span>

            <?php if ($block->displayFinalPrice()): ?>
                <span class="minicart-tax-total">
                    <span class="weee" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Total Incl. Tax')); ?>">
                        <!-- custom logic -->
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($block->getFinalUnitDisplayPriceInclTax()*$qty); ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->displayPriceExclTax() || $block->displayBothPrices()): ?>
    <span class="price-excluding-tax" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Excl. Tax')); ?>">
    <?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
        <span class="minicart-tax-total">
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="minicart-price">
    <?php endif; ?>
        <!-- custom logic -->
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($block->getUnitDisplayPriceExclTax()*$qty); ?>
        </span>

    <?php if ($block->displayPriceWithWeeeDetails()): ?>
        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item)): ?>
            <span class="minicart-tax-info">
            <?php foreach ($this->helper('Magento\Weee\Helper\Data')->getApplied($item) as $tax): ?>
                <span class="weee" data-label="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $tax['title']; ?>">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($tax['amount'], true, true); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </span>

            <?php if ($block->displayFinalPrice()): ?>
                <span class="minicart-tax-total">
                    <span class="weee" data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Total')); ?>">
                        <!-- custom logic -->
                        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatPrice($block->getFinalUnitDisplayPriceExclTax()*$qty); ?>
                    </span>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $block->setZone($originalZone); ?>
```

**In above file i have just comment as custom logic at which place i have added price multiply $qty to get lineitem subtotal.**

Clear cache and check it again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried overriding that file as you suggested but it did not work.  I believe because KO is being used and not that file.  Is there a step beforehand which I'm missing.  Is this the correct file to override `app/code/Magento/Weee/view/frontend/templates/checkout/cart/item/price/sidebar.phtml`, I have flushed the Magento cache and static file cache

Comment: Also, if I followed this approach and did not use KO the mini-cart price would not update automatically with KO ajax when the user added more items to their cart

Comment: I have just given demo for theme override.

Comment: oh ok, it didn't work when I tested it

Comment: Have you keep at this location, app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Weee/templates/checkout/cart/item/price/sidebar.phtml?

Comment: yes, that's the location I used, did you try it, did it work then?

Comment: Which version of magento are you used?

Comment: Its working demo for me i have tested with magento 2.1.3 and above.

Comment: Just remove var folder and clear cache.

Comment: please let me know if you have issue still arise.

Comment: thanks a mil :) got it working. The M2 cache is a mystery to me, sometimes it works as expected at other times it does not!  Out of interest, how did you identify that as the file which needed to be updated?

Comment: I have to do customization for same like display special price and i have debug code and just found that.

Comment: you can assign bounty to answer so question become close.

Comment: I tried already, need to wait 9hrs before SE lets me assign it

Comment: Wah Rakesh +1 from me , It helps me :) @RakeshJesadiya

Comment: @DanielRuf Its working fine for 2.2.5 and 2.2.6, which latest version I have checked.